# Wordpress on Azure WebApp in Virtual Directory - non-application

Tags: wordpress, azure

I'm trying to run WordPress in a virtual directory (application NOT selected), i.e. site.com/blog.

The WordPress sites works fine, except that HTTP POSTs (form submissions) do not work. They return 200, but no action is taken, i.e. Login just returns to login.

The main site at the root is complex, with a large web.config.  If I try to make the "/blog" virtual directory into an application, WordPress fails with tons of errors because of the inherited web.config.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue - a Glimpse module was interfering with PHP. I commented out the offending module in web.config and everything worked as expected on the WordPress side.

Comment: I have the exactly same problem... how exactly did you identify the module that was interfering with PHP? I have a number of modules already 'removed' in the web.config within the virtual directory, but I don't know how to determine which other module is effecting the Wordpress site (if at all!)

Comment: Painfully - I removed them one at a time :-(

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I ended up doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this on my company's website. If you're trying to do it with virtual directories, you're going to have a bad time.

We followed [these instructions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webapps/2013/02/13/hosting-wordpress-in-a-subfolder-of-your-windows-azure-web-site/) and it works like a charm.

The only issues we had were figuring out how to handle rewrite rules from http to https and from non-www to www so that they were also consistent across the blog as well.

Comment: sorry - need a virtual directory so the code isn't hosted in the same code base as the asp.net site.